QGIS - LRS plugin calibration workflow for complex geometry
I have a very extensive vector geometry layer that I am trying to calibrate with the LRS plugin, for use in further measurement analysis.
Might anyone suggest an effective workflow to calibrate a large dataset? The tutorial videos I have seen seem to do it manually.
So far I have tried using QChainage to create start/end points, but trying to link the route ID of the segments to these points using 'Join Attributes by Location' (with intersect) creates many errors.
Ideally the workflow could be incorporated into a model (happy to share if I succeed). I am using 3.36.3-Maidenhead on a Mac.
